# Can background flash sync priority be increased to avoid using sync command frequently?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have too frequent cases of 0-sized files, truncated files or files with garbage past the end when PI 3 Stretch power is lost.
Issuing frequent "sync" commands helps.
I don't know if it can be done for flash, but for USB I've read there are some conf options to switch to/from an always-sync mode at a performance and memory device life cost.

I think there are commands I would have to add throughout to the application code to sync specific files.

Are there options raise and lower the priority/speed of normal background sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there options raise and lower the priority/speed of normal background sync

If you read `man 3 sync`, you'll notice *"The writing, although scheduled, is not necessarily complete upon return from sync()"*, meaning the kernel makes this determination. While `fsync(3)` does block until completion, the priority of the request will remain the same.

This probably makes `sync()` preferable performance wise<sup>1</sup> depending on context -- but another difference between these two system calls is that `fsync` targets a single file descriptor.

Such a setting might be a little oxymoronic, since if the system is not busy, then `sync` calls are probably superfluous.  Keep in mind `sync` is not a *guarantee* that the filesystem cannot become corrupted, since an arbitrary power fail is still *arbitrary*.  Anyway, conversely, if the system is busy, then you can either trust the kernel scheduler or work out your own logic for when and what to prioritize.

The kernel scheduler is probably something you want to trust. It can be configured to behave different ways, but consider:

- If it is a simple FIFO queue, then a "busy" system means the sync events will get spread out more amongst whatever else is happening.
- If it has priorities of one kind or another, those will be taken into account with the scheduling of `sync`.

Finally, use of `sync` *is* about "rais[ing ...] the priority/speed of normal background sync".  Data gets flushed to disk fairly frequently.  By using `sync`, you are essentially just making it more frequent.

All that said, there is a mount parameter (at least, for `ext4` filesystems, see `man ext4`, but probably most others) that can set the maximum amount of time, in seconds, that data can remain cached without syncing:

```
commit=2   # Number of seconds
```

You can add this to the fourth field of `/etc/fstab` for the root filesystem.

---

1. Or at least simpler than using `fsync` on a dedicated thread, if application responsiveness is the issue.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks (whew - that was fast!).
I have also read (I'd love to now if it is true) that on the PI specifically, sync is thorough (maybe excluding a few milliseconds more inside a flash chip).
Seeing that sync can take a minute or 2 after a bunch of new files seems like it is doing lots of work and not just request-and-return.

Comment: flush/close & fsync on log files and sync after major file changes might be my best approach.

Comment: Is there a way to check if things are not synced and I did not incorrectly implement use of sync or fsync?

Comment: *"sync can take a minute or 2"* -> Reminded me of something I had forgotten: https://superuser.com/a/479384/257378 I've edited the uptake of that at the bottom here (`commit=`).  I think this might be the best option you will find.